# Perl $1 variable not defined after regex match

Tags: regex, perl

This is probably a very basic error on my part, but I've been stuck on this problem for ages and it's driving me up the wall!

I am looping through a file of Python code using Perl and identifying its variables. I am using a Perl regex to pick out substrings of alphanumeric characters in between spaces. The regex works fine and identifies the lines that the matches belong to, but when I try to return the actual substring that matches the regex, the capture variable `$1` is undefined.

Here is my regex:

```
if ($line =~ /.*\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+.*/) {
    print $line;
    print $1;
}
```

And here is the error:

```
x = 1
Use of uninitialized value $1 in print at ./vars.pl line 7, <> line 2.
```

As I understand it, `$1` is supposed to return `x`. Where is my code going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not capturing the result:

```
if ($line =~ /.*\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+.*/) {
```

If you want to match a line like `x = 1` and get both parts of it, you need to match on and capture both with parenthesis. A crude approach:

```
if ( $line =~ /^\s* ( \w+ ) \s* = \s* ( \w+ ) \s* $/msx ) {
    my $var = $1;
    my $val = $2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26084343/725418) has been given by [Leeft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3755747/leeft): You need to capture the string by using parentheses. I wanted to mention some other things. In your code:

```
if ($line =~ /.*\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+.*/) {
    print $line;
    print $1;
}
```

You are surrounding your match with `.*\s+`. This is unlikely doing what you think. You never need to use `.*` with `m//`, unless you are capturing a string (or capturing the whole match using [`$&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$&)). The match is not anchored by default, and will match anywhere in the string. To anchor the match you must use `^` or `$`. E.g.:

```
if ('abcdef' =~ /c/)      # returns true
if ('abcdef' =~ /^c/)     # returns false, match anchored to beginning
if ('abcdef' =~ /c$/)     # returns false, match anchored to end
if ('abcdef' =~ /c.*$/)   # returns true
```

As you see in the last example, using `.*` is quite redundant, and to get the match you need only remove the anchor. Or if you wanted to capture the whole string:

```
if ('abcdef' =~ /(c.*)$/) # returns true, captures 'cdef'
```

You can also use `$&`, which contains the entire match, regardless of parentheses.

You are probably using `\s+` to ensure you do not match partial words. You should be aware that there is an escape sequence called word boundary, `\b`. This is a zero-length assertion, that checks that the characters around it are word and non-word.

```
'abc cde fgh' =~ /\bde\b/     # no match
'abc cde fgh' =~ /\bcde\b/    # match
'abc cde fgh' =~ /\babc/      # match
'abc cde fgh' =~ /\s+abc/     # no match! there is no whitespace before 'a'
```

As you see in the last example, using `\s+` fails at start or end of string. Do note that `\b` also matches partially at non-word characters that can be part of words, such as:

```
'aaa-xxx' =~ /\bxxx/          # match
```

You must decide if you want this behaviour or not. If you do not, an alternative to using `\s` is to use the double negated case: `(?!\S)`. This is a zero-length negative look-ahead assertion, looking for non-whitespace. It will be true for whitespace, and for end of string. Use a look-behind to check the other side.

Lastly, you are using `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. This can be replaced with `\w`, although `\w` also includes underscore `_` (and other word characters).

So your regex becomes:

```
/\b(\w+)\b/
```

Or

```
/(?<!\S)(\w+)(?!\S)/
```

Documentation:

- [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) - Perl built-in variables
- [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) - Perl operators
- [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - Perl regular expressions